# prevent synchronously loading of a store

Tags: javascript, extjs, dependencies

I use Ext 4.1.1

I keep getting:

> [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Eml.store.eml.EventSummary'; consider adding Ext.require('Eml.store.eml.EventSummary') above Ext.onReady

I added the store reference to my controller first, but the controller isn't loaded till later.. so I added it as 'requires' but no cigar.. Anyone got a clue what I'm doing wrong?

[image: dependancy problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it doesn't get evaluated during creation, it creates the store before it ever passes the object literal to the define().

Instead, specify the store in initComponent.

Comment: good thinking ;) that was it! What stupid of me not to think of that... :p I'll accept in 7min

Comment: Hi, can you give a sample of the solution please? I've been struggling with that problem for two days now. No one answers. That's why I gave up on ExtJS two years ago, and it seems there's still this problem about solving quickly simple problems..